# CSS3 menu dropdown while resizing browser

Tags: css

In css, sub menus by default open to the right I guess, so what is the css syntax to make them open to the left if there is not enough room. For example, if the browser window is smaller.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Push your code for better understanding

Comment: This can't be made using pure CSS. To achieve this, you need some JavaScript code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you mean with "In css, sub menus by default open to the right"? Are you talking about SELECT-dropdowns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be completely solved with css. It requires java script to determine whether there is enough space to the right (while resizing).

Some pseudo code:

```
if window.innerWidth - submenu.offsetLeft > submenu.offsetWidth
       showMenuToRight();
else
       showMenuToLeft();
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes I am talking about css dropdowns! If you use "left: 100%" for the sub menus, they will in this case open to the right. Problem is if the menu is on the right side of the screen, at the end of the browser, they disappear instead of automatically open to the left where there´s room. In that case I must had javascript :( Thanks.